# Is it possible to debug Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I can't debug global.asax file!

I have some codes in `Application_Start()` method but when I set a break point in the method, it is ignored!

Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try:

- stopping development server in taskbar
- switching the configuration from release to debug

Comment: It's got a minus rating because it's wrong. It's correct to say that you need to be in debug (or else you don't have the pdb files) and you need to capture the server when it starts (because this is when that code is ran) but you won't be able to attach to the process. You need a running process to attach the debugger, the global.asax code is ran in the first few miliseconds of this process starting so it's literally impossible (without using the [correct answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809464/542251)) to attach to the process as it runs this code

Answer (score 94):

A simple way to break in `Application_Start()` is to use the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` class. You can force the application to break by inserting `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` where you would like the debugger to break.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

     // ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I don't have any w3wp process running, I Start Debugging in Visual Studio, and the breakpoint doesn't hit. I guess the debugger attaches too late.

Answer (score 80):

1. Attach the debugger to the IIS process.
2. Open the global.asax file and put in  a breakpoint.
3. Add a space to the web.config file and save the file (this causes the current web application to reset);
4. Refresh / goto a web page on the site.
5. watch in amazement when the debugger stops at your breakpoint. :)

Comment: This is also known as 'Touching the web.config' and can be used for several scenarios when you need to refresh your site without touching IIS. Can't believe it didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. But for me? "computer says no"

Comment: Worked perfectly. When performing step 1 in Visual Studio I had to tick "Show processes from all users" and attach to the IIS process called "w3wp.exe".

Answer (score 8):

`Application_Start()` is invoked once per AppDomain. If you're not hitting your breakpoint, it means the AppDomain was already created, so do the following:

- In your quick-launch bar, there is an icon for the VS web server (its the one which says "Local Host Some Port"). Right click and choose "Stop" or "Close". This should kill the AppDomain.

  - If you're using IIS, you need to restart your site manually.
  - Alternatively, modifying the web config or Global.asax file is usually enough to restart the AppDomain.
- Restart your debugging, you should hit your breakpoints now.

Answer (score 7):

Check that your web application is in debug mode (`<compilation debug="true">` in web.config).

If you're using developer's IIS started by VS, just restart it or rebuild application.

If you're on normal IIS you have two options:

1. For web-site is configured to work with development folder (where you VS web project is deployed) you just have to restart application pool set for that web-site and start debugging before first request reaches server (you can always restart app pool during debug).
2. For web-site that works on another folder or even on remote server you have to attach to the process. To do this you need remote debugger installed on remote machine or your own (depends on web-server location) and use `Debug - Attach to process` menu, enter computer name and then select a process to debug. It is usually a w3wp.exe working in managed mode type.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is normal.

`Application_Start()` is processed by IIS.

But all other methods, for example `Session_Start`, and all others, except `Application_Start()` can be debugged normally.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to the accepted `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` would be

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
   //...
}
```

which shouldn't break the code and should start the debugger even if the service were started with different rights.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `global.asax` and add a new one. In my solution, there has been a `global.asax` and a `global.asax.cs`.

All the methods (`Session_Start`, `Application_Start`, ...) have been in the bot files, but only the ones in the `global.asax` have been considered. So, break points and code in the cs don't do anything.
Only after recreating the file, the `global.asax.cs` had the appropriate methods and they ran.

Comment: I followed the instructions here: http://rossnelson.blogspot.ca/2005/11/fixing-globalasax-in-aspnet-20.html.

Basically, remove the global.asax and add a global application class which recreate the asax with a code behind file which I can then step into.  I am running on IIS and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For me, my debug breakpoint already executed in IIS by the time the debugger is attached. So the solution was to alter global.asax with a little space and save the file. After refresh, my breakpoint is now hit.

Solution here:
https://wakeupandcode.com/hitting-breakpoints-in-global-asax/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thank you! This was the only solution that worked for me.  Add a space inside the `Application` tag, hit save, and then refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Dont expect the Application_Start() function to be called immediately by pressing f5.
Application_Start() is invoked only at the time of first request to the application is made.
Strange but true.

Answer (score 0):

In case all of answers not working, try:

```
<compilation debug="true" ... />
```

in `web.config`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Kill the w3wp process(es) for my application
2. Insert this code where I want it to stop:

```cs
while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
Debugger.Break();
```

3. Start the app with a request to it (e.g. to the root `/` route)
4. Attach to w3wp.exe