# How do I debug the HttpApplication.Start method in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [it is possible to Debug Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960651/it-is-possible-to-debug-global-asax)

I want to debug the HttpApplication.Start method in my Global.asax. Unfortunately, the debugger will rarely hit a the break point at the start of the method, even when I do a clean and rebuilt or iisrest? Is there a method to force this method to be rerun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/12/13/workaround-debugging-global-aspx-cs-application-start-with-asp-net-web-server-within-visual-studio.aspx) is a brief explanation about Debugging Global.aspx.cs `Application_Start()` with ASP.Net Web Server within Visual Studio.

Another method is to force break by as shown below:

```
Protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();            
}
```