# How to set breakpoint in ConfigureAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I need to set a breakpoint in the ConfigureAuth to debug an issue we are having.
The following article claims you can set a breakpoint but this article is C# and I need this to work in VB.NET
https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/
I converted this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  await next.Invoke();
});
```

To this:

```
app.Use(Async Function(context, [next])
            Await [next].Invoke()
        End Function)
```

but I get an error the following error:

> Parameter count mismatch.

Here are a couple of problems.

1. I assumed that "context" was "Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext" but that is an invalid assumption.  "context" in the VB project I think it is "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware"
2. I don't know what the type is for "next"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found here [Is it possible to debug Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960651/is-it-possible-to-debug-global-asax)
per [John Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145483/john-kelly)

This lets me step into it from global.asx

1. Attach the debugger to the IIS process.
2. Open the global.asax file and put in a breakpoint.
3. Add a space to the web.config file and save the file (this causes the current web application to reset);
4. Refresh / goto a web page on the site.
5. watch in amazement when the debugger     stops at your breakpoint.
   :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same Parameter count mismatch issue and came across this https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/84

Essentially the VB equivalent is written like this

```
AppBuilderUseExtensions.Use(app, Async Function(context, [next]) As Task
                                     Await [next]()
                             End Function)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had converted the 'standard app.use' code from a C# app and could not work out why it was not working.  This solved it for me in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Visual Studio plugin **Attach To All The Things** to attach to IIS or IIS Express, which enables you to set a breakpoint in Global.asax or the Startup.cs class.

See
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thebread.AttachToAllTheThings